# Can I change the Icon on an Actionbar Item

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm not trying to change the main Icon , just a menu item's icon.

The Icon is essentially displays whether I am recording at that moment. I change the icon when it's tapped using

```
item.setIcon(R.drawable.recordstart);
```

In this method.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.ab_menu_VRecord) {

        if(recording)
                    {
                       item.setIcon(R.drawable.recordstop);
                    }else{
                       item.setIcon(R.drawable.recordstart);
                    }

        }

        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Anyone know how I can do this outside this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure where you are wanting to change the icon, but you can certainly cache or create a class member variable and point it at the the MenuItem in your Activity or Fragment for example.  After they click it or you inflate it, assign it to the member variable and when you need to change it, you've got a reference or "cached" pointer to it to change the icon.

I think that is a UI change so you might have to be sure that you only call that on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for your response, funny enough while waiting for a response I tried something and got it working, i'm not sure if its the same as what tried to explain but ill post my answer below.

Comment: What you posted is exactly what I was proposing.

Comment: I'll put yours as the answer, I probably didn't understand when you said cache.

Comment: YEah, by cache I just meant fetch it with the findItem call like you did and then assign it to a class level variable that can then be accessed anywhere in the class.  Bad choice of words. I will edit to be a little clearer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
class {

    public MenuItem example;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);       
        example = menu.findItem(R.id.ab_menu_exampleview);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then throughout your class you can use

```
example.setIcon("Your Image");
```

Comment: Exactly my point!! just Defining the MenuItem global would have done it, good to know you found that out, yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!item.isChecked()){
    item.setChecked(true);
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
}else{
    item.setChecked(false);
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.icon2);
}
```

is this?